# Is there any alternative for column range partitioner in spring Bach remote partitioning?

Tags: db2, spring-batch

Just take a normal case where I am taking data from DB2 , doing some business on data and writing it into mongoDB. This I am doing with spring batch column range partition(Remote partitioning) but the problem is in my DB2 table there is no sequential column , so each partition is having different data count. Because of this load is different for each slave. My requirement is to distribute load in slaves equally.

Comment: Hi , could you please tell us how did you solve this problem ? even we have data which is not sequential

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write your own implementation of a `Partitioner`  In a partitioned job, the `Partitioner is responsible for knowing how to divide up the data into the partitions.  Spring Batch really only provides one out of the box, the`MultiResourcePartitioner`.  The column range one found in the framework is actually just an sample.  You can read more about this interface and it's role in the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/Partitioner.html and here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html